# Jersey 2.2: output xml OK, but fails on json

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs

I've run into a weird problem.
I use Jersey 2.2 to do my restful web services (with jersey-media-moxy).
If I produce my output as application/xml, it runs fine.
But if produce my output as application/json, I get "Internal Server Error 500".

My dependency settings in ivy.xml are:

```
<dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.core" name="jersey-server" rev="2.2"/>
<dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.containers" name="jersey-container-servlet-core" rev="2.2"/>
<dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.media" name="jersey-media-moxy" rev="2.2"/>
```

My service class is:

```
@Path("/projects/{companykey: [0-9]*}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class ProjectResource {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProjectResource.class);
    private final Application app = Application.getInstance();
    @GET
    public List<ProjectBase> getProjectBases(
            @PathParam("companykey") String companyKeyStr) {
        ...
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/{projectkey: [0-9]*}")
    public ProjectBase getProjectBase(
            @PathParam("companykey") String companyKeyStr,
            @PathParam("projectkey") String projectKeyStr) {
        int companyKey = Integer.valueOf(companyKeyStr);
        int projObjKey = Integer.valueOf(projectKeyStr);
        logger.debug(MessageFormat.format("get project {1} of company {0}",
                companyKey, projObjKey));
        ProjectBase project = null;
        try {
            project = app.getProjectIF().getProjectBase(companyKey, projObjKey);
            if (project == null) throw new WebApplicationException(404);
            return project;
        } catch (ServerException se) {
            logger.warn("get project fails ! " + se);
            throw new WebApplicationException(500);
        }
    }
    ...
} 

//class end
```

If I ask for the xml output (visit http://biz.loc.net:8080/tm/rest/projects/100/104), I get:

```
<projectBase>
<_checkTopicAccess>false</_checkTopicAccess>
<_checkTaskAccess>false</_checkTaskAccess>
....
```

If I ask for the json output, I get:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Status report
>
> message Internal Server Error
>
> description The server encountered an internal error (Internal Server Error) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

I do not find any error messages in my app's log file or Tomcat's log file, so I have no
idea what is going on.

Does anyone know any possible reason for this problem? Really appreciate ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the entity code? Are you missing an empty constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, the following code snippet is my entity clas:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ProjectBase implements UdaEnabled, SdaEnabled, FormBean {
    private int projObjKey;
    private String projName;
    //...
    private Timestamp createdAt;
    //...
    //...  
    @XmlElement(name = "createdAt")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TimestampAdapter.class)
    public Timestamp getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    // non-args Constructor
    public ProjectBase() {
        init();
    }
}
```

It does has an empty constructor, although these's a `init()` inside.

As I said, I think it is weird because producing xml is OK.